# asp.net mvc hide download page opening

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5.2

My case ı have big excel exports ım never stored thıs fıles my server ım create and download client so ı need to keep scope or my export operations is failing my button is this

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Open" onclick="window.open('@Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "Sec")')" />
```

How ı can open hide window for downloading my files?

Comment: You won't hide download popup given by browser?

Comment: No ım trying hide tab my code works now but open empty tab ı dont need thıs tab but ı need thıs tab scope for preparation excel if ı kıll thıs scope ı have eroor aouth disconnectedtoken so my problem ıs hide tab